# Input string was not in a correct format in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm using entity framework to get an int from SQL But I get this error when I open the browser

> "Input string was not in a correct format"

Code:

```
string DailyRatee = entity.CarsCategories
                          .Where(x => x.ID == CatId)
                          .Select(p => p.DailyRate).ToString();
int DailyRate = int.Parse(DailyRatee);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you even try to debug this and see what the error was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `ToString` with `FirstOrDefault` to returns the first element of the sequence instead of applying `ToString` to the `DailyRate` column if your are sure that `DailyRate` is of type `string` and also contains a valid number that is convertible to `int`:

```
var DailyRatee = entity.CarsCategories.Where(x => x.ID == CatId)
                       .Select(p => p.DailyRate)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I changed a property type from string to int on one of my classes and forgot to remove the string configuration in the entity framework `Configure()` method:

```
            builder.Property(e => e.WasAStringPropertyNowAndInt)
            .HasConversion<string>()
            .HasMaxLength(50);
```